# Variadic typedefs, or "Bimaps done the C++0x way"

Tags: c++11, bimap

Short question: Can I typedef a variadic argument pack? I need `template <typename ...T> struct Forward { typedef T... args; };`.

---

Long version:

I was thinking about reimplementing the excellent [boost bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/one_minute_tutorial.html) in C++0x. Recall that a bimap of two types `S` and `T` is a `std::set` of *relations* between `S x` and `T y`. The objects themselves are stored in two independent internal containers, and the relations track the associated iterators I suppose; both types can serve as keys via "left" and "right" lookup. Depending on the choice of internal containers, values may be unique or not, e.g. if the left container is a set and the right container is a multiset, then one `x` can map to many different `y`s, and right lookup gives an equal-range. Popular internal containers are `set`, `multiset`, `vector` and `list`, and maybe the `unordered_*` versions too.

So we need a type which accepts two containers as template parameters:

```
class Bimap<S, T, std::set, std::multiset>
```

But we must accept that the containers can take arbitrary many arguments, so we need to pass all those, too. If we just needed *one* set of variadic arguments, it wouldn't be a problem, since we could pass those directly. But now we need *two* sets of arguments, so I want to write a forwarder, to be used like so:

```
Bimap<int, int, std::set, std::set, Forward<std::less<int>, MyAllocator>, Forward<std::greater<int>, YourAllocator>> x;
```

Here's the template I came up with:

```
#include <set>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename ...Args>
struct Forward
{
  typedef Args... args; // Problem here!!
  static const std::size_t size = sizeof...(Args);
};

template <typename S, typename T,
          template <typename ...SArgs> class SCont,
          template <typename ...TArgs> class TCont,
          typename SForward = Forward<>, typename TForward = Forward<>>
class Bimap
{
  typedef SCont<S, typename SForward::args> left_type;
  typedef TCont<T, typename TForward::args> right_type;

  template <typename LeftIt, typename RightIt> struct Relation; // to be implemented

  typedef Relation<typename left_type::const_iterator, typename right_type::const_iterator> relation_type;

};


int main()
{
  Bimap<int, int, std::set, std::set, Forward<std::less<int>>, Forward<std::greater<int>>> x;
}
```

Unfortunately, in the indicated line in `Forward` I cannot figure out how to typedef the parameter pack! (The commented line gives a compiler error.)

[I suppose I could go for a lazy version `Bimap<std::set<int, MyPred>, std::multiset<char, YourPred>> x;` and extract the types via `LeftCont::value_type` and `RightCont::value_type`, but I thought it'd be nicer if I could make the key types my primary template arguments and allow defaulting to `std::set` containers.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by encapsulating the variadic argument pack in a tuple and later using the following two helper template structs to forward the actual variadic arguments:

```
template<typename PackR, typename PackL>
struct cat;

template<typename ...R, typename ...L>
struct cat<std::tuple<R...>, std::tuple<L...>>
{
        typedef std::tuple<R..., L...> type;
};
```

and

```
template<typename Pack, template<typename ...T> class Receiver>
struct Unpack;

template<typename ...Args, template<typename ...T> class Receiver>
struct Unpack<std::tuple<Args...>, Receiver>
{
        typedef Receiver<Args...> type;
};
```

your code sample would look like this:

```
#include <set>
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>

template<typename PackR, typename PackL>
struct Cat;

template<typename ...R, typename ...L>
struct Cat<std::tuple<R...>, std::tuple<L...>>
{
        typedef std::tuple<R..., L...> type;
};

template<typename Pack, template<typename ...T> class Receiver>
struct Unpack;

template<typename ...Args, template<typename ...T> class Receiver>
struct Unpack<std::tuple<Args...>, Receiver>
{
        typedef Receiver<Args...> type;
};

template<typename ...Args>
struct Forward
{    
        //typedef Args... args; // Problem here!!
        typedef std::tuple<Args...> args; // Workaround

        static const std::size_t size = sizeof...(Args);
};

template<typename S, typename T, 
        template<typename ...SArgs> class SCont, 
        template<typename ...TArgs> class TCont, 
        typename SForward = Forward<> ,
        typename TForward = Forward<>>
class Bimap
{
        //typedef SCont<S, typename SForward::args> left_type;
        //typedef TCont<T, typename TForward::args> right_type;
        typedef typename Unpack<typename Cat<std::tuple<S>, typename SForward::args>::type, SCont>::type left_type; //Workaround
        typedef typename Unpack<typename Cat<std::tuple<T>, typename TForward::args>::type, TCont>::type right_type; //Workaround

        template<typename LeftIt, typename RightIt> struct Relation; // to be implemented

        typedef Relation<typename left_type::const_iterator, typename right_type::const_iterator> relation_type;

};

int main()
{
    Bimap<int, int, std::set, std::set, Forward<std::less<int>> , Forward<std::greater<int>>> x;
}
```

which compiles just fine under gcc 4.6.0

Comment: Wow, excellent! I didn't realize you can have variadic arguments _followed_ by other arguments in a template. Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can typedef a tuple. However, I wouldn't know how to then get the types back out again.

The easiest thing to do would be to just accept two full types.

Comment: Yeah, that'd be easy, but somehow not very elegant. For instance, I'd like to be able to give defaults like `Bimap<int, int>`. In the laziest case I'd just use Boost.Bimap ;-)