# Print vector of coordinates obtained from a text file in a specific format in C++

Tags: c++, vector, convex-hull

The following is the code that I am working on -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

struct coord {
long x,y;
};

int main()
{
ifstream nos("numbers.txt");
vector< long > values;
double val;
while ( nos >> val )
{
    values.push_back(val);
}

copy(values.begin(), values.end(), ostream_iterator<double>(cout, "\n" ));
return 0;

}
```

I understand the initial **struct** is not necessary here, but I wish to use that. I want my input text file to be something like this -

```
1,2
2,3
4,5
```

I then use my program, to input these numbers into a **vector** and print out that vector **in the same format**

Could anyone tell me what's the correct way of doing so?

I have referred to the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/c-printing-out-the-contents-of-a-vector) for the code, but I need to read and print out in the format mentioned above and I am not sure what's the best way to proceed.

For better clarity - I am attempting to implement a convex hull algorithm. I am trying to get better at programming at the same time and hence such a jump.

Comment: So you want to read an int, ignore a comma, then an int, one pair per line? Is that the *exact* format you want to process?

Comment: In one part you say `print out that vector in the same format` and then later on you say `I need to read and print out in a specific format`. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question**: Why are you mixing `double` **and** `long`? I'll assume you want to use `long` throughout the code. The easiest way to do what you want is to add a dummy variable that reads the `,` between the numbers:

```
int main()
{
ifstream nos("numbers.txt");
vector< long > values;
long val1, val2;
char dummy;
while ( nos >> val1 >> dummy >> val2)
{
    values.push_back(val1);
    values.push_back(val2);
}

copy(values.begin(), values.end(), ostream_iterator<long>(cout, "\n" ));
}
```

Also, you defined a struct named `coord`, but you don't use it in the code. If you would like to use that, you could use the following code:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const coord& c)
{
    os << c.x << " " << c.y;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
ifstream nos("numbers.txt");
vector< coord > values;
coord c;
char dummy;
while ( nos >> c.x >> dummy >> c.y )
{
    values.push_back(c);
}

copy(values.begin(), values.end(), ostream_iterator<coord>(cout, "\n" ));
}
```

Also, in C++11 you could change the code to:

```
long x, y;
char dummy;
while ( nos >> x >> dummy >> y )
{
    values.emplace_back(coord{x, y});
}
```

Or you could also look into `std::pair<long, long>` for placing your coordinates in.

Comment: I was initially attempting just with the struct. I later came across that link I mentioned in my post and added that piece of code. And thank you for clarifying this for me!

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little overkill for something this simple, but I would overload the ostream and istream output and input operators, respectively.

EDIT: I guess since a struct has default public variables you don't need the friend class, but I'll keep it in, as it is the common practice for overloading << and >>

```
struct coord {
    long x,y;

    friend class ostream;
    friend class istream;
};

istream& operator>>( istream& is, coord& c )
{
     char comma;
     return is >> c.x >> comma >> c.y;
}

ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const coord& c )
{
     char comma = ',';
     return os << c.x << comma << c.y;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream nos("numbers.txt");
    vector< coord > values;

    coord val;
    while ( nos >> val )
        values.push_back(val);

    for each( value : values )
        cout << value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```