# Print out a std::vector<std::wstring>

Tags: c++, stl, visual-studio-2005

I was trying to adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/c-printing-out-the-contents-of-a-vector) to print out the contents of `std::vector<std::wstring>` using std::copy but I don't understand how that code is working well enough, and can't get it to compile. What should the code be?

I used Rob's example but it doesn't work:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> keys = ...;
std::copy(keys.begin(), keys.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::wstring>(std::wcout, " "));
```

I get the error:

```
1>error C2665: 'std::ostream_iterator<_Ty>::ostream_iterator' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::wstring
1>        ]
1>        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\iterator(300): could be 'std::ostream_iterator<_Ty>::ostream_iterator(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const _Elem *)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::wstring,
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>        ]
1>        while trying to match the argument list '(std::wostream, const char [2])'
```

Why is it telling me `_Elem=char` when I use `wcout` which is of type `wostream`?

Comment: Please provide a code example and information about the error message demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use `wstring, wchar_t` as the template parameters, and `wcout` as the output stream:

```
std::copy(v.begin(), 
          v.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<std::wstring, wchar_t>(std::wcout, L"\n"));
```

Test program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main () {
  std::vector<std::wstring> v;
  v.push_back(L"Hello");
  v.push_back(L"World");
  std::copy(v.begin(),
            v.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::wstring, wchar_t>(std::wcout, L"\n"));
}
```

Comment: the `"\n"` doesn't need to be wide too?

Comment: This isn't working for me. I realised I hadn't mentioned I'm using VC++2K5, in case there's a known glitch...

Comment: @John - sorry for the bad advice. Try this one.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the correction - out of interest did the previous version work on your compiler or did you merely write it without testing?

Comment: I wrote it without testing.