# How to cout NumericVectors?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm quite new to programming with Rcpp so I'm trying out new things to see how everything works. 
I wrote a small programm to compare two NumericVectors with the match() function. I also wanted to print out the input Vectors and the Output but it doesn't seem to work since I don't get the entries of the Vectors back but the storage place (or something like that). 
I haven't found any kind of "print" function for NumericVectors but maybe there's another way? Any help will be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector vergl(NumericVector eins, NumericVector zwei){
 IntegerVector out = match(eins, zwei);
 cout << eins << endl;
 cout << zwei << endl;
 cout << match(eins, zwei) << endl;
 return out;
 }
```

A small example:

```
vergl(c(1,2,3),c(2,3,4))
```

The output:

```
> vergl(c(1,2,3),c(2,3,4))
0xa1923c0
0xa192408
0xb6d7038
[1] NA  1  2
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just iterate over the vector and print the elements.

Comment: See there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/c-printing-out-the-contents-of-a-vector

Comment: http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-rcout/

Comment: The answer by @user2079303 is correct, but useless. The answer by Rene is plain off as we're not talking `std::vector`.  We'd need to define a corresponding `operator<<` for NumericVector which has not happened yet. I use the Armadillo vectors as in the Rcpp Gallery post, and Roland's answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked using Armadillo :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-rcout](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-rcout) .

```cpp
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>   

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector vergl(NumericVector eins, NumericVector zwei){
 IntegerVector out = match(eins, zwei);
 Rcout << as<arma::rowvec>(eins) << std::endl;
 Rcout << as<arma::rowvec>(zwei) << std::endl;
 Rcout << as<arma::rowvec>(out) << std::endl;
 return out;
}
```

In R:

```
vergl(c(1,2,3),c(2,3,4))
#   1.0000   2.0000   3.0000
#
#   2.0000   3.0000   4.0000
#
#      nan   1.0000   2.0000
#
#[1] NA  1  2
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this `Rf_PrintValue(eins);` or `Function print("print"); print(eins);` or similar as shown in the `display` function in the example.

For example, assuming this is in Rf_PrintValue.cpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector vergl(NumericVector eins, NumericVector zwei) {

 IntegerVector out = match(eins, zwei);

 Rf_PrintValue(eins);
 Rf_PrintValue(zwei);
 Rf_PrintValue(match(eins, zwei));

 Function print("print");
 print(out);

 Function display("display");
 display("out", out);

 return out;
}

/*** R
display <- function(name, x) { cat(name, ":\n", sep = ""); print(x) }
vergl(c(1,2,3),c(2,3,4))
*/
```

we can run it like this.  The first three output vectors come from the `Rf_PrintValue` statements, the fourth from the `print` statement and the fifth is from the `display` function and the last is the output of the `verg1` function:

```
> library(Rcpp)
> sourceCpp("Rf_PrintValue.cpp")

> display <- function(name, x) { cat(name, ":\n", sep = ""); print(x) }

> vergl(c(1,2,3),c(2,3,4))
[1] 1 2 3
[1] 2 3 4
[1] NA  1  2
[1] NA  1  2
out:
[1] NA  1  2
[1] NA  1  2
```

**Revised** Changed the second solution and added an example.  Also added `display` to example.

Comment: Also added a new second approach.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck `Function paste("paste"); Function message("message"); message(paste(out, Rcpp::Named("collapse", " ")));` would be nicer.

Comment: @Roland, Yech.  That's a lot of code and it does not work for all objects.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me!