# How to print a vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, stdvector, cout

I have to print the values of a pair. For showing the value of the first value of the pair there isn't any problem. But how I can print the second value of the pair?
The representation can't be changed.

```
typedef vector<char> _vots;
typedef pair<string,_vots> PartitPolitic;

ostream& operator<<(ostream &o, PartitPolitic x){
   o << x.first << endl;
   o << x.second << endl;->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR
   return o;
}

int main(){
      vector<PartitPolitic> partit;
      string q;
      string s;
      getline(cin,descripcio);
      while (q!="*"){
          getline(cin,s)
          _vots v(s.begin(),s.end());
          PartitPolitic f(descripcio,v);
          partit.push_back(f);
          getline(cin,descripcio);
     }
     vector<PartitPolitic>::iterator it =partit.begin();
     while(it!=partit.end()){
        cout << *it << endl;
        it++;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/c-printing-out-the-contents-of-a-vector

Answer (score 2):

> how I can print the second value of the pair?

The second value is a `vector<char>`, so to print that you need to provide an `operator<<` overload for `vector`, defining how you want a vector to be printed:

```
template<typename elem_type>
ostream& operator<<(ostream &o, vector<elem_type> const& v) {
   for (const elem_type& e : v)
      o << e << ",";
   return o;
}
```

or you can simply output the vector manually in `operator<<(ostream&, PartitPolitic)`:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &o, PartitPolitic x) {
   o << x.first << endl;
   for (char e : x.second)
      o << e << ",";
   return o;
}
```