# How to properly overload << operator for standard library container

Tags: c++

For example, I want to use code like this:

```
std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::cout << vec;
```

Is there a way, to overload << operator?

Comment: If you want to use `<<` then see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23397700/4342498) on the dupe target

Comment: Sure, it should look like `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::vector<int>)`.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I observe that you are pretty much nailing the dupes. Why don't you help closing it, being a gold badge owner yourself. :-)

Comment: @iammilind I tried but it was closed by Cory 16 seconds before I tried to close it.  That last one you closed I didn't because I wasn't 100% sure what the OP wanted.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: No, it should look like `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::vector<int>&)`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oops, I missed the third `&`.