# Error message/Vector of user input numbers

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors

Here is the error I am getting:
Exercise11.cxx:29:13: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'vector')

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
   cout << "Kaitlin Stevers" << endl;
   cout << "Exercise 11 - Vectors" << endl;
   cout << "November 12, 2016" <<endl;
   cout << endl;
   cout << endl;
   int size;
   cout << " How many numbers would you like the vector to hold? " << endl;
   cin >> size;
   vector<int> numbers;
   int bnumbers;

   for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
   {
       cout << "Enter a number: " << endl;
       cin >> bnumbers;
       numbers.push_back(bnumbers); 
    }
    //display the numbers stored in order
    cout << "The numbers in order are: " << endl;
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout<<numbers[i]<< " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

The error comes up on the part of the code that says:

```
cout << numbers << endl;
```

Second question:

How do I use vent.reverse(); to reverse the vector and then display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a loop to print the vector:

```
for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
    cout<<numbers[i]<< " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you all you need to know: `operator<<` is not defined between `std::cout` and `std::vector`.

The line that fails is this one...

```
cout << numbers << endl;
```

...because `cout` is a `ostream` and `numbers` is a `vector`. [Here's a list of supported types that can be streamed into `ostream`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)

---

Consider using a `for` loop to print out the contents of `numbers`:

```
cout << "The numbers in order are: " << endl;

for(const auto& x : numbers)
{ 
    cout << x << " ";
}

cout << endl;
```

---

If you do not have access to C++11 features, strongly consider researching them  and updating your compiler. The code below if C++03-compliant:

```
cout << "The numbers in order are: " << endl;

for(std::size_t i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
{ 
    cout << numbers[i] << " ";
}

cout << endl;
```

Comment: What is 'const auto&' ?

Comment: Look into [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) and [range `for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). They're both C++11 features.

Comment: I used that code and got the error: Exercise11.cxx:27:15: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]

Comment: @KatieStevers: you need C++11 support. Check my latest edit for a C++03-compliant solution

Comment: I don't think my teacher will let me use that. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `cout << numbers` because there is no defined way to output a vector. If you want to print out the data in a vector you need to iterate through and print each element separately. More information is available [How to print out the contents of a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/how-to-print-out-the-contents-of-a-vector)

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using C++11 features

```
for (auto it = numbers.begin(); it < numbers.end(); it ++)
    cout << (*it) << "\t";
```