# What is the correct way to output a whole vector/array? [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays, containers

What is the correct way in C++ to output a whole container (in this case the targets are vectors and arrays)? Possibly I'd like to put spaces in it, or sort them like this:

```
1: (first element)

2: (second element)

3: (third element)
```

and so on...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print out the contents of a vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/how-to-print-out-the-contents-of-a-vector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is by looping on each element:

```
// Array
for (int i = 0; i < size_of_array; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << ": " << array[i] << "\n";
}
```

The same for a vector would be the same, but replace `i < size_of_array;` with `i < name_of_vector.size();`