# How do I add a string to a vector (and subsequently display it)?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, stdvector, stdstring

I am 4 hours-new to C++ and have hit a brick wall with string vectors. When trying to add multiple strings to a string vector, I keep erroring out. I'd like to use `push_back`.

I would also like to display this string vector, but I'm not sure how (I know how to display non-vectors). Given that I have not been able to add a string to a vector of strings, I did not attempt to display the vector of strings yet.

**profile.hpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Profile 
{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string city;
    std::string country;
    int age;
    std::vector<std::string> hobbies;

public:
    std::vector<std::string> add_hobbies(std::string new_hobbies);
};
```

**profile.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "profile.hpp"

Profile::Profile(std::string new_name, int new_age, std::string new_city, std::string new_country)
    : name(new_name), age(new_age), city(new_city), country(new_country) 
{}

void Profile::add_hobbies(std::string new_hobbies) 
{
    hobbies.push_back(new_hobbies);
}
```

**app.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "profile.hpp"
int main()
{
    Profile sam("Sam Drakkila", 30, "New York", "USA");
    sam.add_hobbies("Play golf", "Read books", "Eat tennis balls"); // This doesn't seem to work. 
}
```

`g++ app.cpp profile.cpp`. Prints a massive log of errors.

Comment: For display the vector of strings, you could have googled it: [How to print out the contents of a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/how-to-print-out-the-contents-of-a-vector)

Answer (score 5):

You have the following problems in your code:

1. You have declared `add_hobbies` returns `std::vector<std::string>`,
   but in definition you have returned `void`. Presumably, you should have declared as a `void` function as it seems to be a setter function.
2. Secondly, you are passing a number of strings instead of a single string which
   you defined here:

   ```
   void Profile::add_hobbies(std::string new_hobbies) //>>> as per defenition, only one string can be passed!
   //                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   If you want to pass an arbitrary number of strings, you could use`std::initializer_list<std::string>` instead.
3. Thirdly, you are missing the constructor declaration in the header file. Add
   in the definition of class `profile.hpp`

   ```
   Profile(std::string new_name, int new_age, std::string new_city, std::string new_country);
   ```
4. Last but not least, you need to include the `<string>` header in
   order to use `std::string`(credits *@πάντα ῥεῖ*)

That means, **([See live online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/t4kH2BEdBUtjBYmW))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>           // std::string
#include <initializer_list> // std::initializer_list

class Profile 
{    
private:
    // ... other members
    std::vector<std::string> hobbies;

public:
    // ... other member functions
    void add_hobbies(std::initializer_list<std::string> new_hobbies)
  //^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    {
        hobbies.reserve(hobbies.size() + new_hobbies.size()); // reserve memory to avoid, unwanted reallocations
        for (const auto& hobby : new_hobbies) hobbies.emplace_back(hobby);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Profile sam{};
    sam.add_hobbies({ "Play golf", "Read books", "Eat tennis balls" }); // now works
    //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

---

Alternatively using *[variadic templates](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/)* and [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) feature *[fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)*.
 **([See live online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cMzYki2FnquCcnu0))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>      // std::string
#include <type_traits> // std::enable_if, std::is_same, std::common_type

using namespace std::literals;

class Profile 
{
private:
    // ... other members
    std::vector<std::string> hobbies;

public:
    // ... other member functions
    template<typename... Args> // sfinae to restrict the Args type to be only std::string s
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::common_type_t<Args...>, std::string>>
        add_hobbies(Args&& ... args)
    {
        hobbies.reserve(hobbies.size() + sizeof...(Args));
        (hobbies.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Profile sam{};
    sam.add_hobbies("Play golf"s, "Read books"s, "Eat tennis balls"s); // now works
    //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: Just a small comment, for _reserve_ to work as intended, you want the current size + initializer list size (instead of only the initializer list).

Comment: @JeJo Also `#include <string>` is missing in the OP's code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes I missed that... Have added. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `add_hobbies` as returning a vector in your class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors in your code:

Missing constructor declaration:

```
Profile(std::string new_name, int new_age, std::string new_city, std::string new_country);
```

Mismatch between return type of the declaration and definition of `add_hobbies`, should be `void` (since you're not returning anything).

```
void Profile::add_hobbies(std::string new_hobbies) { // ... }
```

You're also trying to pass 3 of them, while the function only has 1 parameter:

```
void add_hobbies(std::string const& h1, std::string const& h2, std::string const& h3);

// ... 

void Profile::add_hobbies(std::string const& h1, std::string const& h2, std::string const& h3) {
  hobbies.push_back(h1);
  hobbies.push_back(h2);
  hobbies.push_back(h3);
}
```

Comment: "_Passing `const char[]` instead of `std::string` to `add_hobbies`..._" This isn't an issue. `const char*` (not `[]`) in the parameter will be implicitly cast to `std::string`. Everything else seems on point. :)

Comment: @TrebledJ oopsie