# C++ Error why isn't this vector outputting?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm trying to output the path vector but it won't output...

```cpp
int main (){
    vector<string> path; {"John", "Dave", "Peter", "Charlie", "Michael";};
    sort(path.begin(), path.end());
    cout<<path[5]<<endl;
}
```

I want to see

```
Charlie 
Dave 
John 
Michael 
Peter
```

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: Exited, segmentation fault

Comment: Your vector is empty, accessing its 5th element is UB.

Comment: `path; {` should be `path = {`. Also the semicolon after "Michael" needs to be removed.

Comment: Even after correcting the other errors, you're still attempting to access beyond the end of the vector. You have 5 elements so your maximum index value is 4.

Comment: @Oliver vector start from "0" so if you have 5 elements you can access up to index number 4 (path[0] to path[4]), also remove those excessive semicolons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print out the contents of a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/how-to-print-out-the-contents-of-a-vector) (assuming the other bugs are fixed)

Answer (score 4):

You have too many semicolons, try this syntax instead

```
vector<string> path {"John", "Dave", "Peter", "Charlie", "Michael"};
```

Read more about initialization list syntax here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

You don't want a semicolon after the identifier, nor a semicolon in the `{}` list, but only one at the end of the statement.

Additionally, `path[5]` would be an attempt to use the sixth element, but you've only attempted to define 5.

```
  vector<string> path {"John", "Dave", "Peter", "Charlie", "Michael"};
  sort(path.begin(), path.end());
  cout<< path[4] <<endl;
```

Output:

```
Peter
```

Comment: How would I get it to output say 30 strings inside a vector?

Comment: @Oliver one way is to use a loop. This answer seems pretty thorough: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10758845/487892