# Returning a vector from a function in order to print the contents

Tags: c++, string, function, vector

My program has a function named 'WordLadder' that uses BFS to make a path from one word in a dictionary to another. I was given a starter code that prints the number of nodes in the path, but I want to print the path itself. Currently, I have appended the words to a vector as they enter a queue but I am not able to return the vector as part of my 'WordLadder' function in order to print it in the main program.

I just want the program to print a path based on the two words I picked, i.e. "TOON - POON - POIN - POIE - PLIE - PLEE - PLEA", if the start word is "TOON" in the dictionary and the target word is "PLEA" in the dictionary.

I tried to declare the vector outside of the function and print it in main with this code, but I was unsuccessful.

```
void print(std::vector < int >
  const & transformation) {
  std::cout << "The vector elements are : ";

  for (int i = 0; i < transformation.size(); i++)
    std::cout << transformation.at(i) << ' ';
}
```

I have attempted to return the vector inside of the function, but I receive this error

```
 error: no viable conversion
      from returned value of type
      'vector<std::__cxx11::string>' (aka
      'vector<basic_string<char> >') to
      function return type 'int'
          return transformation;
```

Here is my code. Any help would be appreciated, as I am new to C++.

```
// To check if strings differ by exactly one character 
bool nextWord(string & a, string & b) {
  int count = 0; // counts how many differences there
  int n = a.length();

  // Iterator that loops through all characters and returns false if there is more than one different letter 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[i] != b[i]) {
      count++;
    }

    if (count > 1) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return count == 1 ? true : false;
}

// A queue item to store the words
struct QItem {
  string word;
};

// Returns length of shortest chain to reach 'target' from 'start' using minimum number of adjacent moves. D is dictionary 
int wordLadder(string & start, string & target, set < string > & ew) {
  //Create vector to store path in a
  vector < string > transformation;

  // Create a queue for BFS and insert 'start' as source vertex 
  queue < QItem > Q;
  QItem item = {
    start
  };
  Q.push(item);

  // While queue is not empty 
  while (!Q.empty()) {

    // Take the front word 
    QItem curr = Q.front();
    transformation.push_back(Q.front().word);
    Q.pop();

    // Go through all words of dictionary 
    for (set < string > ::iterator it = ew.begin(); it != ew.end(); it++) {
      // Proccess the next word according to BFS
      string temp = * it;
      if (nextWord(curr.word, temp)) {

        // Add this word to queue from the dictionary
        item.word = temp;
        Q.push(item);

        // Pop from dictionary so that this word is not repeated
        ew.erase(temp);

        // If we reached target 
        if (temp == target) {
          return trasformation;
        }

      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

// Driver program 
int main() {
  string start;
  string target;

  // make dictionary 
  std::ifstream file("english-words.txt");
  set < string > ew;

  copy(istream_iterator < string > (file),
    istream_iterator < string > (),
    inserter(ew, ew.end()));

  cout << endl;
  cout << "Enter Start Word" << endl;
  cin >> start;
  cout << "Enter Target Word" << endl;
  cin >> target;

  cout << wordLadder(start, target, ew);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/how-to-print-out-the-contents-of-a-vector

Comment: The function `wordLadder` has return type `int` but one path returns `transformation`. `transformation` is a `std::vector<std::string>`. The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: Not a bug, but in `return count == 1 ? true : false;` the condition already is a boolean, so `return count == 1;` will do just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems.

You were on the right track when you said *"I tried to declare the vector outside of the function and print it in main..."*

So, change `wordLadder` to take the vector by reference.

```
int wordLadder(vector<string> &transformation, string & start, string & target, set < string > & ew)
```

Then declare it in `main` and *pass* it to `wordLadder`

```
vector<string> t;
wordLadder(t, start, target, ew);
print(t);
```

You will have to also change `print` to take a vector of the right type, ie. `string` and not int

```
void print(std::vector < string > &transformation)
```