# Iterating over unordered_map of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-map

I know this is some basic stuff but I can't manage to iterate over an `unordered_map` of `std::vectors` and print the content of each vector. My `unordered_map` looks like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int> > _dict;
```

And for now I can just print the `first` attribute of the map:

```
for (auto &it : _dict)
{
    std::cout << it.first <<std::endl;
}
```

But it gives me an error when trying to print the `second` attribute. Does anyone know how I can achieve that ? Thanks!

Comment: There ain't a standard way to stream a vector, so you need to write something specific

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print out the contents of a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/how-to-print-out-the-contents-of-a-vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### C++17: Structured binding declaration in a range-based for loop

As of C++17, you may use a [*structured binding declaration*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) as the *range declaration* in a [*range-based for loop*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), along with [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) and [`std::ostream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) to write the consecutive `std::vector` elements to `std::cout`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int> > dict =  {
        {"foo", {1, 2, 3}},
        {"bar", {1, 2, 3}}
    };
    
    for (const auto& [key, v] : dict) {
        std::cout << key << ": ";
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << "\n";
    } 
    // bar: 1 2 3 
    // foo: 1 2 3 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use an inner loop for the vector.

The string is only one element, it can be printed as is, the vector is a collection of elements so it stands to reason that you need a loop to print its contents:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>> _dict;

for (auto &it : _dict)
{
    for (auto &i : it.second) // it.second is the vector
    {
        std::cout << i;
    }
}
```

If you want to print a particular item in the vector you need to access the position of that item you want to print:

```
for (auto &it : _dict)
{
    std::cout << it.second.at(0) << std::endl; //print the first element of the vector
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `range-for loop` to print the contents of the `std::vector <int>`:

```
for(auto it : _dict){
    std::cout << it.first << ": ";

    for(int item : it.second){
        std::cout << item << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```