# "no match for ‘operator<<’" when using "cout <<" to output a vector<map<int,int>> type variable

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I caught an error of `"no match for ‘operator<<’"` when using `"cout <<"`  to output a `vector<map<int,int>>` type variable on C++ code. The code I wrote and the error message is following:(the code is about bit-full search)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
int main(){
    int N,K;
  cin >> N >> K;
  vector<int> A(N);
  for(int i = 0;i<N;i++){
    cin >> A.at(i);
  }
  bool ans = false;
  vector<map<int,int>> all_cont(20);
  for(int tmp = 0;tmp < 1 << 20;tmp++){
    bitset<20> s(tmp);

    map<int,int> cont;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<N;i++){
     if(s.test(i)){
       cont[i] = A.at(i);
       sum += A.at(i);
     }
    }
    
    if(sum == K){
     ans = true;
     all_cont.push_back(cont);
    }

  }
  if(ans){
   cout << "YES" <<endl;
   cout << all_cont << endl;
  }else{
   cout << "NO" <<endl;
  }
}
```

```
./Main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./Main.cpp:33:9: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘std::vector<std::map<int, int> >’)
   33 |    cout << all_cont << endl;
      |    ~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~
      |    |       |
      |    |       std::vector<std::map<int, int> >
      |    std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/sstream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/complex:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ccomplex:39,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/stdc++.h:54,
                 from ./Main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:108:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  108 |       operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:108:36: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::vector<std::map<int, int> >’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type&)’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>&)’}
  108 |       operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:117:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>; std:...
```

What is going wrong? The compiler is GCC 9.2.1.

Comment: there is no output operator for a `vector<map<int,int>>` in the standard library. If you want one you need to write it. Or just use loops and print individual elements

Comment: see eg here for the vector part: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10750057/4117728

Comment: Tip: Don't, just don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`. Only thing worse would be to use `#import` instead of `#include`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h for more informations.

Comment: It looks like you're learning programming and C++ from a competition site. Please don't do that. Get [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and take classes, that will help you much better than any such site will.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to replace the cout to loops and print but I got a new error. I would post a new question about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `std::ostream::operator<<` is not defined for `std::vector<std::map<int,int>>` by default. So you have to overload it. I added a full example.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef map<int, int> MapT;
typedef vector<MapT> DataT;

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const DataT& data) {
    for (auto const& m : data) {
        for (auto const& p : m)
            os << "[" << p.first << ", " << p.second << "]";    
        os << std::endl;
    }
    return os;
}

int main() {
    DataT data;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        MapT m;
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; ++k)
            m.insert(make_pair(k, i));
        data.push_back(m);
    }

    std::cout << data;

}
```