# Printing out the content of train and test set from my dataset in c++

Tags: c++, dataset

I am trying to print out the content of both train and test sets, i need the proper line of codes to do this, please help

```
void split_dataset(int perc_train,
    vector<vector<float>>& vec_X_dataset, vector<int>& vec_Y_dataset,
    vector<vector<float>>& vec_X_train, vector<int>& vec_Y_train,
    vector<vector<float>>& vec_X_test, vector<int>& vec_Y_test) {
    size_t len = vec_X_dataset.size();
    size_t len2 = vec_Y_dataset.size();
    size_t len3 = vec_X_train.size();
    size_t len4 = vec_X_test.size();
    size_t division = static_cast<size_t>(len * (perc_train * 0.01));
    vector<float> data_point;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (i < division) {
            vec_X_train.push_back(vec_X_dataset[i]);
            vec_Y_train.push_back(vec_Y_dataset[i]);
            
                   }
        else {
            vec_X_test.push_back(vec_X_dataset[i]);
            vec_Y_test.push_back(vec_Y_dataset[i]);
        }
            
    }

    cout << "len:" << len << "  " << "len2:" << len2 << "  " << "division:" << division <<"  " <<"len3:"<< len3 ;
    cout<< "len4:" << len4 << endl;
}
```

Comment: We need to info to answer this. What is the actual problem you're having? How do you want it printed? In what way does your code not do what you expect?

Comment: I want to print the training set and testing set, i don't know how

Comment: As in you don't know how to print to the screen? You'll need to know the basics of outputting to the console https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

Comment: If you don't know how to print a vector in particular, then this question should help (found by googling "how to print vector c++") https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/how-do-i-print-out-the-contents-of-a-vector

Comment: If it's something more than this, you'll need to edit the question to explain precisely what it is you want.