# How do I print a vector of chars using fmt?

Tags: c++, c++14, std, null-terminated, fmt

I have a `const std::vector<char>` - *not* null-terminated. I want to print it using the fmt library, without making a copy of the vector.

I would have hoped that specifying the precision would suffice, but [the fmt documentation](https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html) says that :

> Note that a C string must be null-terminated even if precision is specified.

Well, mine isn't. Must I make a copy and pad it with `\0`, or is there something else I can do?

Comment: Well, that's what it says, and no alternatives are mentioned, so that's the only option.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: But maybe fmt has some magical sequence printing capability?

Comment: You are aware of `cout <<` in a loop? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/how-do-i-print-out-the-contents-of-a-vector

Comment: Do you want to interpret it as a string? If so, you could always just make a `string_view` and use that.

Comment: @IlCapitano: So, I'm actually not in C++20 for this, but that would work, yes.

Comment: @tevemadar: For reasons, I can't work with an ostream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**: `std::cout << fmt::format("{}", fmt::string_view{v.data(), v.size()});`

---

So, fmt accepts two kinds of "strings":

- **C-style** - just a pointer, must be null-terminated.
- **`std::string`-like** - data + length.

Since C++17, C++ officially has the reference-type, `std::string`-like [string view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) class, which could refer to your vector-of-chars. (without copying anything) - and `fmt` can print these. Problem is, you may not be in C++17. But `fmt` itself also has to face this problem internally, so it's actually [got you covered](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/8c7cf51395cc9140503be507e18107110766cbdd/include/fmt/core.h#L346) - in whatever version of the standard you can get fmt itself to compile, in particular C++14:

```
const std::vector<char> v;
fmt::string_view sv(v.data(), v.size());
auto str = fmt::format("{}", sv);
std::cout << str;
```

---

Thanks @eerorika for making me think of string views.

Comment: That's really neat.

Comment: @vitaut: Indeed, I had thought it might not be available before C++17, but it turns out it is.

Answer (score 8):

If you could upgrade to C++17, then you could use a strig view argument instead of pointer to char:

```
const std::vector<char> v;
std::string_view sv(v.data(), v.size());
fmt::format("{}", sv);
```

Answer (score 5):

What about using [`fmt::join`](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html)?

> Returns a view that formats range with elements separated by sep.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/4q1zGn4xo)

```cpp
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<char> v{'a', 'b', 'c'};
    fmt::print("{}", fmt::join(v, ""));
}

// Outputs:
//
//   abc
```

Comment: It might be a little over the top for a very large vector, but yeah, definitely. +1.