# Question about `has_const_iterator`/`has_begin_end`

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

The following code comes from [cxx-prettyprint](https://louisdx.github.io/cxx-prettyprint/) , which implements detecting whether type T has a corresponding member

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<type_traits> 
using namespace std;
struct sfinae_base
{
  using yes = char;
  using no = yes[2];
};

template <typename T>
struct has_const_iterator : private sfinae_base
{
private:
  template <typename C> static yes& test(typename C::const_iterator*);
  template <typename C> static no& test(...);
public:
  static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(yes);
  using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct has_begin_end : private sfinae_base
{
private:
  template <typename C>
  static yes& f(typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<decltype(static_cast<typename C::const_iterator(C::*)() const>(&C::begin)),
    typename C::const_iterator(C::*)() const>::value>::type*);

  template <typename C> static no& f(...);

  template <typename C>
  static yes& g(typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<decltype(static_cast<typename C::const_iterator(C::*)() const>(&C::end)),
    typename C::const_iterator(C::*)() const>::value, void>::type*);

  template <typename C> static no& g(...);

public:
  static bool const beg_value = sizeof(f<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(yes);
  static bool const end_value = sizeof(g<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(yes);
};

int main()
{
  vector<int> sa{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
  cout << has_const_iterator<vector<int>>::value;
  cout<<has_begin_end<vector<int>>::beg_value;
  cout << has_begin_end<vector<int>>::end_value;
  return 0;
}
```

[run it online](https://godbolt.org/z/GnPrzaeTo)

Some time later I read someone else's blog and changed it to this

```cpp
#include<utility>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
struct has_const_iterator
{
private:
  template <typename U>
  static constexpr decltype(std::declval<U::const_iterator>(), bool()) test(int) { return true; }
  template <typename U>
  static constexpr bool test(...) { return false; }
public:
  static const bool value = test<T>(1); //为什么这个不对？
  using type = T;
};
template <typename T>
struct has_begin_end
{
private:
  template <typename U>
  static constexpr decltype(std::declval<U>().begin(), bool()) f(int) { return true; }
  template <typename U>
  static constexpr bool f(...) { return false; }
  template <typename U>
  static constexpr decltype(std::declval<U>().end(), bool()) g(int) { return true; }
  template <typename U>
  static constexpr bool g(...) { return false; }

public:
  static bool const beg_value = f<T>(2);
  static bool const end_value = g<T>(2);
};
int main()
{
  vector<int> sa{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
  cout << has_const_iterator<vector<int>>::value;
  cout<<has_begin_end<vector<int>>::beg_value;
  cout << has_begin_end<vector<int>>::end_value;
  return 0;
}
```

[run it online](https://godbolt.org/z/Mn6b1aKqe)

For the first piece of code it shows 111
For the second piece of code it shows 011
Snippet 2 was working fine a few months ago, but not now.
My question is, what's wrong with the second one,and why it was good before and now goes wrong?

Added: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55270925/13792395), what does he mean by `introduce ODR violations`?

Comment: Why do you think the "Added" is related? That answer talks about the issue when you have two different definitions of an operator<< for eg `std::vector` in your project, eg because some libxy provides one and some other libabc provides one, and both placed them in global namespace.

Comment: Why do you include the `has_begin_end` part if it doesn't change?

Comment: please add the missing includes so that others can compile the code

Comment: @Nelfeal You're right, I can remove it from the minimal reproducible code.
But I thought maybe someone would give a c++20 based implementation, so I put it there so others would rewrite it too by the way, haha.

Comment: @Kargath If you want a C++20 (I assume concept-based?) implementation, then ask another question. `has_begin_end` does not belong in this one.

Comment: By the way, I know why it it works before and didn't work now , because msvc used to allow not to write typename, it's more strict now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you force a call the overload of `has_const_iterator::test` that returns `true` (by removing the other):

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct has_const_iterator
{
private:
  template <typename U>
  static constexpr decltype(std::declval<U::const_iterator>(), bool()) test(int) { return true; }
  //template <typename U>
  //static constexpr bool test(...) { return false; }
public:
  static const bool value = test<T>(1);
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << has_const_iterator<std::vector<int>>::value;
}
```

then you get this error message (more or less):

> error: dependent-name 'U::const_iterator' is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
> note: say 'typename U::const_iterator' if a type is meant

It tells you exactly what's wrong: `typename` is missing before `U::const_iterator`. The reason is that `U::const_iterator` is a [dependent name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) (it could be a type or a variable, for example, depending on what `U` is exactly), so you need to specify that it refers to a type.

Note that the previous version does use `typename`:

```
template <typename C> static yes& test(typename C::const_iterator*);
//-------------------------------------^^^^^^^^
```

This version works:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct has_const_iterator
{
private:
  template <typename U>
  static constexpr decltype(std::declval<typename U::const_iterator>(), bool()) test(int) { return true; }
  template <typename U>
  static constexpr bool test(...) { return false; }
public:
  static const bool value = test<T>(1);
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << has_const_iterator<std::vector<int>>::value;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/encY8ovP8)

Comment: its not really "unecessary code" but its required to get `false` when SFINAE kicks in. Anyhow, nice way to see the actual error, by turning SFINAE into a hard error that gets reported

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I haven't removed the `false` overload, I commented it out. The unnecessary code is everything else from the question, including the whole `has_begin_end` part and the `using type = T;` line.

Comment: ah ok, now I understand. I tend to ignore comments, hence I read "removed" as also refering to the `// ....`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I cleaned it up since it could cause confusion.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me how to debug such problems

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `typename` because `U::const_iterator` is a dependant name.

```
template <typename T>
struct has_const_iterator
{
private:
  template <typename U>
  static constexpr decltype(std::declval<typename U::const_iterator>(), bool()) test(int) { return true; }
                                         // ^^ 
  template <typename U>
  static constexpr bool test(...) { return false; }
public:
  static const bool value = test<T>(1); //为什么这个不对？
  using type = T;
};
```

After fixing that it prints expected results: https://godbolt.org/z/jP9G95Pb1l.

I did not find yet a compiler that produced output `111` without the typename though.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the meaning of [dependant name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name), I have seen it while learning c++, but it appears in specific question, i didn't realize it