# On c++ vector how to cout the values from a vector function

Tags: c++, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

    vector<int> newvector() {
        vector<int> v;
        v.push_back(5);
        return v;
    }
int main(){
cout << newvector();

}
```

When I run this code I got an error in cout how to run this properly to return a out as vector

Comment: Something like `for(auto i : newvector()) cout << i << '\n';`

Comment: `cout` doesn't print `vector` items directly. You need to iterate your `vector` and then print their items. More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/how-do-i-print-out-the-contents-of-a-vector

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate through each element of the vector and `std::cout` it individually.

```cpp
int main(){
   vector<int> myVector = newvector();
   for(int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)
      cout << myVector[i] << '\n';

   /* Alternatively
   for(int element : myVector)
      cout << element << '\n';
   */

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ya ok but in java we can use toString() to print the value  so is any way here to do that ?

Comment: I am afraid there isn't such a thing here. You may need to write your own function or overload this stream insertion operator to achieve such a thing.